# zeros in c() after round()

Tags: r, rounding, scientific-notation

I'm trying to print a vector with:

```
total_nb_visits <- 20302079
total_nb_visits_y1 <- 19299803
total_nb_visitors <- 17707555
total_nb_visitors_y1 <- 17196674
CVR <- 0.02274954
CVR_y1 <- 0.02293334
```

When I do:

```
exportable <- rbind(c(total_nb_visits,total_nb_visits_y1,((total_nb_visits-total_nb_visits_y1)/total_nb_visits_y1)*100),
                    c(total_nb_visitors,total_nb_visitors_y1,((total_nb_visitors-total_nb_visitors_y1)/total_nb_visitors_y1)*100),
                    c(CVR,CVR_y1,((CVR-CVR_y1)/CVR_y1)))
```

I'm getting:

```
exportable
                  [,1]              [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 20302079.00000000 19299803.00000000  5.193192905
[2,] 17707555.00000000 17196674.00000000  2.970812844
[3,]        0.02274954        0.02293334 -0.008014533
```

And I'd like to get:

```
                  [,1]              [,2]         [,3]
[1,]          20302079          19299803  5.193192905
[2,]          17707555          17196674  2.970812844
[3,]        0.02274954        0.02293334 -0.008014533
```

And `round()` is not working...

I should add that I've been also playing with `options(scipen=999)` to delete the scientific notation...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks !

Comment: You cannot store different types in your matrix, your desired output shows integers while still containing decimals. The presentation may be done differently in a table for example, but the storage of the object will remain as your result.

Comment: Thank you @KevinArseneau. What could I do to print the table shown?
If instead of storing the data in a matrix I use another type of object it could work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use prettynum like this:

```
exportable <- as.data.table(
  rbind(
    c(prettyNum(total_nb_visits), 
      total_nb_visits_y1,  round(((total_nb_visits - total_nb_visits_y1) / total_nb_visits_y1) * 100, 9)), 
    c(total_nb_visitors, 
      total_nb_visitors_y1, 
      round(((total_nb_visitors - total_nb_visitors_y1) / total_nb_visitors_y1) * 100, 9)), 
    c(CVR,CVR_y1, round((CVR-CVR_y1) / CVR_y1, 9))))
```

the only downside is that it will convert the values to character but you will have your pretty output!

Comment: So it's not possible to keep them as numeric? I must convert them into characters?